# When spectral radius of a Perron-Frobenius matrix is less than its trace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, outer-product

Let $H$ be a $n\times n$ non-negative matrix. I am interested in matrices $H$ that satisfy the following condition: $\lambda_{\max}(H) \leq \operatorname{tr}(H)$.

Moreover, let $x,y \in \mathbb C^n$. What can I infer about bi-homogeneous polynomial $h(x, y) = x^\top H y$?

For example for $n = 2$ my condition is equivalent to $\det(H) > 0$ thus a polynomial $h(x, y)$ doesn't have zeroes in $\mathbb H_+ \times \mathbb H_-$. Can I get something similar for $n>2$?

Comment: What are the $\lambda_i$? How are they ordered? Do you assume them to be all real?

Comment: I have added answers to your questions as a comment to my question, please find above.

Comment: How do you prove that the non-negativity of $\sum\lambda_i\lambda_j$ implies your condition? I don't see it.

Comment: Here is the calculation: $(tr(H))^2 = (\sum \lambda_i )^2 = \sum \lambda_i^2 + 2\sum \lambda_i \lambda_j \ge \sum \lambda_i^2 \ge \lambda_{max}^2$. Now recall that both $trace(H)$ and $\lambda_{max}(H)$ are real positive and extract the square root.

Comment: The last step is wrong since you add squares of complex numbers... For example, if $n=3$ and $\lambda_2 = a+bi$, $\lambda_3 = a-bi$, then $\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2 = 2a^2-2b^2$, which could be negative.

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks! I will update my question. Nevertheless, I still have a question about how can I describe matrices $H$ with $\lambda_{max} \le tr(H)$

Comment: Here is a counterexample: Let the eigenvalues $-a+ib$, $-a-ib$, and $c = \sqrt 3b-a$ be given, where $a,b>0$ and $b>\sqrt 3a$. We have $c>0$ and $c^2 = a^2+b^2+2b(b-\sqrt 3a) > a^2+b^2$. Then there exists a non-negative matrix $H\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ with exactly these eigenvalues (see Prop. 4 in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82135723.pdf). We have $\sum\lambda_i\lambda_j = 2ac + a^2+b^2 = (b-\sqrt 3a)^2 > 0$, but $\operatorname{tr}(H) = -3a+\sqrt 3b < c = \lambda_{\max}$.

Comment: You can, however, adapt your first approach by taking the absolute value because$$(\operatorname{tr}(H))^2 = \left|\sum\lambda_i\right|^2 = \sum|\lambda_i|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}\sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}.$$